# how can I send a string/signal from android to raspberry pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

I need to send a signal of some sort from an android device to my Raspberry Pi. I have been looking around a bit and have found a few posts about running a server on the Raspberry Pi to listen for the string being sent. In my case I don't need any specific string or information to be sent, just the simplest way to tell the Pi to give power to one of the GPIO pins.

I have never worked with a server and apparently if I want to do this over a network I will need to make use of one, so I am wondering if there is any simpler way to send a signal to activate the GPIO pins.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, like you are at company and your devices is at home, you have to use web service or http to remote control the GPIO pins.

But if these two things are at the same place, like in the same room, I suggest you have a try on Bluetooth. Bluetooth is avaliable in Raspberry 3, otherwise you can use adapter to acess bluetooth.

You can google some project to get deeper information.

Comment: as far as I know, build a simple http server on raspberry is the simplest way to do this job. you can google lots of tutorial about this.